# How do I remove alphabetical grouping of acronyms in the list?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I would like an acronym list with equal vertical space between each acronym. My list is grouping acronyms that start with the same letter. How is this avoided?

Here is the code for a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with this "problem":

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-superragged}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Acronyms and Abbreviations}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % remove trailing dot
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newacronym[longplural={Affinity Diagrams}]{ad}{AD}{Affinity Diagram}
\newacronym{dom}{DOM}{Document Object Model}
\newacronym{svg}{SVG}{Scalable Vector Graphics}
\newacronym{spa}{SPA}{Single Page Application}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype]

\section{First section}

Here we go... \gls{ad}, \gls{dom}, \gls{svg} and \gls{spa}!
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heiko's answer works perfectly in your case, since you are printing only one glossary.

In fact, adding `nogroupskip` option at loading time, you change the behavior globally, i.e. for all glossaries.

Just in case you need to define it locally to one glossary, you can define a new style that redefines just that aspect:

```
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
  \glossarystyle{super}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}
```

and at printing time use

```
\printglossary[style=modsuper, type=\acronymtype]
```

The result is the same, but if you want to define another glossary where you want the gap between groups, this solution may be of interest.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-superragged}
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
  \glossarystyle{super}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Acronyms and Abbreviations}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % remove trailing dot
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newacronym[longplural={Affinity Diagrams}]{ad}{AD}{Affinity Diagram}
\newacronym{dom}{DOM}{Document Object Model}
\newacronym{svg}{SVG}{Scalable Vector Graphics}
\newacronym{spa}{SPA}{Single Page Application}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\printglossary[style=modsuper, type=\acronymtype]

\section{First section}

Here we go... \gls{ad}, \gls{dom}, \gls{svg} and \gls{spa}!
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

### Addendum

If you want to add some vertical space between items, you can define the new style as:

```
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
  \glossarystyle{super}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[5pt]}%
}
```

and adjust `5pt` to whatever you like. In this case the output will be:

[image]

Comment: I chose to define a new style because I have texlive 2012 with an old version of glossaries which does not support `nogroupskip`. How do I adjust the distance between the items in the list? I think it looks to compact now...

Comment: @swenedo See the addendum

Comment: `\printglossary` now supports `nogroupskip` as an option to locally change the setting for that specific glossary.

Answer (score 11):

The vertical gap between is controlled by option `nogroupskip`. From the [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) of package `glossaries`:

> **nogroupskip**   This is a boolean option. If no value is specified, `true` is assumed. When set to `true`, this option suppresses the
>   default vertical gap between groups used by some of the predefined
>   styles. The default setting is `nogroupskip=false`.

Also note the `nopostdot` option instead of the manual command.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc,nogroupskip,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-superragged}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Acronyms and Abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newacronym[longplural={Affinity Diagrams}]{ad}{AD}{Affinity Diagram}
\newacronym{dom}{DOM}{Document Object Model}
\newacronym{svg}{SVG}{Scalable Vector Graphics}
\newacronym{spa}{SPA}{Single Page Application}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype]

\section{First section}

Here we go... \gls{ad}, \gls{dom}, \gls{svg} and \gls{spa}!
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]