# Why is the vertical space between entries not equal in the glossary?

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I am using the glossaries package and when trying to avoid linebreaks in long descriptions with the `listdotted` style I noticed that the vertical space between the entries is not equal for all of them.

[image]

The red line is always the same size and as you can see, sometimes the distance between entries is smaller (blue rectangle), sometimes equal. This is present in the printed page too.

Is there a specific cause for this and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Surely this has a cause, but without a minimal example showing the issue it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Its the visual gap between letter groups.  You can switch it off with `nogroupskip`.

Comment: That is because the option to group alphabetically is enabled, you could obtain the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129301/154390)...