# Changing \parskip in List of Abbreviations (glossaries)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am creating a document, in which I need a List of Abbreviations. I liked the style alttree, so I use it.

Now, **I want to change the distance between the entries in the LOA**, so to say change the `\parskip` value locally.

**I found a solution myself** with the help of an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129294/how-do-i-remove-alphabetical-grouping-of-acronyms-in-the-list), which is shown in the MWE below. Problem: **neither am I sure that this does not potentially crash something else, nor do I know if its the best way to do it**, so these would be my questions here.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\newacronym[sort=WHO]{WHO}{WHO}{World Health Organisation}
\newacronym[sort=EDS]{EDS}{EDS}{Energy dispersive spectroscopy}
\newacronym[sort=ABC]{ABC}{ABC}{Alphabet}
\newacronym[sort=LaTeX]{LaTeX}{LaTeX}{Lamport TeX}
\newacronym[sort=Acr]{Acr}{Acr}{Acronym}

\glsfindwidesttoplevelname

%%%% This here is the part I added
\newglossarystyle{modalttree}{%
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
    \glossarystyle{alttree}%
} 
%%%%

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
 \printacronyms[style=modalttree, title={List of Acronyms}]
 \glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

Result with `alttree`-style (former result):
[image]

Result with modded `modalttree`-style (MWE above):
[image]

---

You can see, at least it *works*. But, e.g. the distance between the heading and the first entry increases also, which has not been intended. So, is this ***somehow*** a correct way to deal with this? It's the first time I did some "hacky" thing in LaTex, so my experience is shallow. Thanks for your suggestions, e.g. such that improve the above-mentioned circumstance. :)