# glossaries – acronyms spaced out for no apparent reason (?)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I've just added acronyms to my document with: `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]`. Inserting the first few acronyms worked out fine but suddenly, there were large gaps between acronyms. I can't really wrap my head around why overleaf/latex does that (see attached picture). Can this be corrected or do I have to live with it? It looks like Ive intentionally spaced it out so its not really appealing. Edit: Upon adding further acronyms with the same letter I guess that latex just puts words that start with the same letter into one group, am I right? It looks less whacky the more words are added with similar latters.

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{cdo}{CDO}{Collaterized Debt Obligation}
\newacronym{spv}{SPV}{Special Purpose Vehicle}
\newacronym{repo}{REPO}{Repurchase Operation}
\newacronym{abx}{ABX}{Asset Backed Securities Index}
\newacronym{ecb}{ECB}{European Central Bank}
\newacronym{ltro}{LTRO}{Longer Term Refinancing Operation}
\newacronym{mro}{MRO}{Main Refinancing Operation}
\newacronym{eoina}{EOINA}{Euro Overnight Index Average}
\newacronym{qe}{QE}{Quantitative Easing}
\newacronym{libor}{LIBOR}{London Interbank Offered Rate}
\newacronym{ted}{TED}{Treasury Bill Eurodollar Difference}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: You are right with your assumption about glossaries grouping entries that share the same first letter. If you don't want this, add the option `nogroupskip` to the `glossaries` package options.

Comment: See also: [How do I remove alphabetical grouping of acronyms in the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129294/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thank you very much. Looks a thousand times better now :)