# Irregular line spacing in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I use a relatively simple implementation of package `glossaries` to create a acronym list. I create the output with the command:

```
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym, nonumberlist, title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
```

The list created has irregular line spacing for reasons unknown to me.
[image: acronym list]

Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You get the bigger space always a new letter of the alphabet is the first letter (first a..., first b, first c)

Comment: Right, thanks. I hadn't noticed that at all. I have found the possibility to disable this with the option `nogroupskip`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129294/how-do-i-remove-alphabetical-grouping-of-acronyms-in-the-list